# File picker not showing up

Tags: android

I am making a simple app for android that should let users pick a text file from the internal storage and upload it on the server.

Here is the code I am using to init file chooser on button click:

```
private static final int LOAD_FILE_RESULT = 100;

@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:

                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    intent.setType("text/plain");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, LOAD_FILE_RESULT);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }}}

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOAD_FILE_RESULT:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // Code to get the URI of the selected file goes here
}
}
}
```

When I do the test on Nexus 5X emulator(API 25), everything works fine. However,
when I test on a physical Samsung Galaxy S3, when I press the button it just shows the window to log in to Dropbox, there is no option to select a file from storage. Why is this happening?

This is the screen that pops up: [image]

Do I need to implement a separate filepicker for older APIs?

Comment: intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); Remove those lines.

Comment: I just tried that. Some new options showed up, but no file chooser. I think that newer version of android have some kind of file chooser already built int, and for the older versions you have to install some kind of file chooser or include it in you application code.